# Can't corda observer node reissue cash?

Tags: corda

I am trying to persist only specific states into vault state of Observer node.

In my usecase Observer is cash issuer, Where observer issues cash and transfer to other nodes in corda network. When corda nodes perform transaction, as observer all cash states of nodes also gets persist on observer node.

When try to reissue cash from Observer gives below error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Collection contains no element matching the predicate.
        at net.corda.node.services.keys.PersistentKeyManagementService.getSigningKeyPair(PersistentKeyManagementService.kt:110) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.keys.PersistentKeyManagementService.sign(PersistentKeyManagementService.kt:101) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.toSignedTransaction(TransactionBuilder.kt:224) ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.node.ServiceHub$DefaultImpls.signInitialTransaction(ServiceHub.kt:219) ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.node.ServiceHub$DefaultImpls.signInitialTransaction(ServiceHub.kt:233) ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.api.ServiceHubInternal$DefaultImpls.signInitialTransaction(ServiceHubInternal.kt) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$ServiceHubInternalImpl.signInitialTransaction(AbstractNode.kt:836) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.node.ServiceHub$DefaultImpls.signInitialTransaction(ServiceHub.kt:255) ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.api.ServiceHubInternal$DefaultImpls.signInitialTransaction(ServiceHubInternal.kt) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$ServiceHubInternalImpl.signInitialTransaction(AbstractNode.kt:836) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.finance.flows.CashPaymentFlow.call(CashPaymentFlow.kt:66) ~[corda-finance-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.finance.flows.CashPaymentFlow.call(CashPaymentFlow.kt:26) ~[corda-finance-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:290) ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.finance.flows.CashIssueAndPaymentFlow.call(CashIssueAndPaymentFlow.kt:41) ~[corda-finance-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.finance.flows.CashIssueAndPaymentFlow.call(CashIssueAndPaymentFlow.kt:24) ~[corda-finance-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:96) [corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:44) [corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
```

I want to reissue new cash from observer node, but however it try to use unconsumed cash state persist during observing transaction. I think observer can't issue or transfer cash.

Edit:

On Regulator node, calling CashIssueAndPaymentFlow through API as below:

```
rpcOps.startFlow(::CashIssueAndPaymentFlow, issueAmount, OpaqueBytes.of(0), toTransferNode, false, notaryIdentity).returnValue.get()
```

On Other Node Flow sending transaction to observer:

```
val observer = serviceHub.networkMapCache.getPeerByLegalName(CordaX500Name.parse(FundTransferConstants.OBSERVER_NAME)) ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown observer name.")
        subFlow(BroadcastTransactionTransfer.BroadcastTransactionToObserversTransfer(finalTx, listOf(observer)))
```

Scenario is below:

1. Cash issue and Transfer to node using CashIssueAndPaymentFlow on Regulator node.
2. Do transaction involving cash and send transaction to observer (Regulator). Cash is spend to other party using Cash.generateSpend()
3. Again try to reissue cash, gives above issue.

I think similar issue posted on git at https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/4368

Need help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `ServiceHub.signInitialTransaction` without passing a specific key, the platform tries to sign the transaction with your node's default key:

```
fun signInitialTransaction(builder: TransactionBuilder): SignedTransaction = 
    signInitialTransaction(builder, legalIdentityKey)

private val legalIdentityKey: PublicKey get() = 
    this.myInfo.legalIdentitiesAndCerts.first().owningKey
```

Because the observer node isn't one of the signers (e.g. because they're not the owner of the cash), this exception is thrown.

Comment: Scenario is different. In my use case observer is also cash issuer. Initially can issue cash from observer to bank nodes. After performing transaction between banks, their unspent cash states also gets persisted on observer node. Now observer try to issue money, it should use newly issued cash, instead of that it try to use observer specific cash state which persisted duriing observing transaction, and gives above error.

Comment: Can you update the question with your flow code? There must be an issue with how you are retrieving the cash.

Comment: I have editted question with flow. Cash issue and transfer is done using "CashIssueAndPaymentFlow" on regulator node. After performing transaction with cash & sending it to Regulator, on Regulator vault I can clearly see unspent cash. Reissue cash on regulator node will gives error: java.util.NoSuchElementException: "Collection contains no element matching the predicate." In this usecase Regulator is observer as well as issuer.